# Android's main reference (developer.android.com) seems to be incorrect about "Creating an App Widget Configuration Activity"

Tags: android, android-activity, configuration, android-appwidget

"developers.android.com" at [this section of this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring) has pointed:

> The `onUpdate()` method **will not be called** when the App Widget is created (the system will not send the `ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE` broadcast when a configuration Activity is launched). It is the responsibility of the configuration Activity to request an update from the AppWidgetManager when the App Widget is first created.

So I created a simple *Android Studio "Hello World!" Project* and then made the minimal changes to it (see the end).

Now when I build my App and then try to insert its widget on home screen, the configuration Activity will be launched and ***immediately*** these messages will appear in logcat window:

```xml
12-23 01:20:54.429 19010-19010/com.example.widgettest I/XXX: Received action: android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED
12-23 01:20:54.459 19010-19010/com.example.widgettest I/XXX: Received action: android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE
```

**While according to the mentioned reference the second log must not appear at all!**

---

The minimal changes I made to *Android Studio "Hello World!" Project*:

1. Added into **AndroidManifest.xml** file and between `<application></application>` tags:

   ```xml
   <receiver android:name=".ExampleAppWidgetProvider">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
       </intent-filter>
       <meta-data
           android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
           android:resource="@xml/example_appwidget_info" />
   </receiver>

   <activity android:name=".ExampleAppWidgetConfigure">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```
2. Added the file res/xml/**example_appwidget_info.xml**:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:configure="com.example.widgettest.ExampleAppWidgetConfigure"
       android:initialLayout="@layout/example_appwidget"
       android:minHeight="40dp"
       android:minWidth="40dp"
       android:previewImage="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000">
   </appwidget-provider>
   ```
3. Added the file res/layout/**example_appwidget.xml**:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/button"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:text="Click Me"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

4. Added the file **ExampleAppWidgetConfigure.java** (empty Activity class):

   ```java
   package com.example.widgettest;

   public class ExampleAppWidgetConfigure extends android.app.Activity {
   }
   ```
5. Added the file **ExampleAppWidgetProvider.java**:

   ```java
   package com.example.widgettest;

   import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.util.Log;

   public class ExampleAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           Log.i("XXX", "Received action: " + intent.getAction());
       }
   }
   ```